Determine which Monitor a window is running on and get his size
i want to change the width and height of my window based on the resolution of the monitor where the app window is running.
i use this code to get the monitor information:
var screen = Screen.FromHandle(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
double Height = screen.WorkingArea.Height;
double Width = screen.WorkingArea.Width;

I'm getting the right display name, but the Width and Height are not good. My second monitor for example is: 2560x1440 and i'm getting this: 4267x2400
Thank you for your help.
Edit:
I think i found the problem, it's happen because of the scaling factor of my screens.
My primary screen is: 250%, and my second is: 150%
so i tried to retrieve the scaling like this:
var screen = Screen.FromHandle(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
int screenWidth = screen.Bounds.Width;
int screenHeight = screen.Bounds.Height;
float dpiX = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero).DpiX;
float dpiY = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero).DpiY;
float scaleX = dpiX / 96f;
float scaleY = dpiY / 96f;

Now the problem is that i'm getting only the 250% and not the 150% of the second monitor

How do you get the width and height ? Please post all the relevant code in a form of a [mre].

I added the width and the height

Try using the Bounds property of the Screen.

It's not working, i'm getting the same result

I edited my question with more information, the issue is the scaling factor of the monitors

Is scaling set to 200% perchance?

Maybe this can help. One of the answers akso handles DPI (scaling).

I finally found the solution:
First we need to determine the used Monitor:
var screen = Screen.FromHandle(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);

Get the Working Area Width and Height
int screenWidth = screen.WorkingArea.Width;
int screenHeight = screen.WorkingArea.Height;

Retreive the Scaling Factor
float dpiX = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero).DpiX;
float dpiY = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero).DpiY;
float scaleX = dpiX / 96f;
float scaleY = dpiY / 96f;

Set the Width and Height by dividing the Working Area Width and Height by the scaling factor, here i want only 98% of the Width and Height because my window is rounded and i want to be able to drag it
this.Width = (screenWidth / scaleX) * 0.98;
this.Height = (screenHeight / scaleY) * 0.98;

Bonus: Centering the screen:
The value is not the same if the Monitor is not Primary, because for the Primary the Left is automatically 0 for the Second monitor or others we need to find it.
In this example, the Width and Height are only 98% of the Actual Width and Height so we need to calculate the difference between the Width and Height of the monitor and the actual dimensions and dividing by 2 to be in the center.
If the monitor is not Primary:
if (!screen.DeviceName.Contains("1"))
{
    this.Left = screen.Bounds.Left / scaleX + (((screen.WorkingArea.Width / scaleX) - this.Width) / 2);
    this.Top = screen.Bounds.Top / scaleX + (((screen.WorkingArea.Height / scaleX) - this.Height) / 2);
}

If the monitor is Primary:
else
{
    this.Left = ((screen.WorkingArea.Width / scaleX) - this.Width) / 2;
    this.Top = ((screen.WorkingArea.Height / scaleX) - this.Height) / 2;
}

Now you will be able to drag your window in which monitor you want and it will automatically resize it according to the monitor resolution and scaling and center it.

Try this
public static Rect GetCurrentScreenWorkArea(this Window window)
        {
            var screen = Screen.FromPoint(new Point((int) window.Left, (int) window.Top));
            var dpiScale = VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(window);

            return new Rect {Width = screen.WorkingArea.Width / dpiScale.DpiScaleX, Height = screen.WorkingArea.Height / dpiScale.DpiScaleY};
        }


I got the same problem

i think it's related to the scaling factor of the screen

All you need to do is to set dpiAwareness (PerMonitorV2) in the application manifest. This is a must-have setting when working under Per-Monitor DPI environment. See Setting default awareness with the application manifest
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <windowsSettings>
    <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitorV2</dpiAwareness>
  </windowsSettings>
</application>

